# viewing promise result in debug mode javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij for debugging my NodeJS app, and while on debugging mode,

I've been wondering if that would be possible to use the Debugger console to execute a promise (including a http request) and view it's result.

I've only managed to get the console to print me it's a Promise, but I'm looking to get the result, similar to the functionality Google chrome is offering.

Comment: Yes, enable the JS debugger plugin if not already enabled and set a break point in the JS file where you can capture the promise & result.

Answer (score 1):

You can launch Node.js in debugging mode, e.g. `node --inspect index.js`. It prints a link that when pasted in Chrome, opens debugger with the same features you'd see in a regular Chrome dev tools.

See https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/

Comment: @Zivpolack what are you trying to achieve typing the code in the console? Getting `Promise {<pending>}` printed out is an expected result, as it is an immediate return value of any promise. If you want to debug your code, a better way would be to switch to *Sources* tab in Chrome debugger and put some breakpoints where you want to inspect the results. Or just add a `debugger` line in your code and wait for the debugger to stop execution when it comes across one.